# Embed boost binaries to xcode project

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

I'm currently working on a C++14 project in OSX using boost libraries.

I am able to compile & link the project incl. the boost libraries.

But, while trying to run the executable file in another computer I'm required to install boost first.. using `brew install boost`.

Is it possible to remove this dependency some how?

Comment: Instead of `-lboost_whatever` you statically link with `libboost_whatever.a`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I've removed the -lboost flags and added to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. the `.a` files.. it works locally but on another mac I still get such errors: `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_date_time.dylib`

Comment: That means you are *not* linking statically with the `.a` files but still dynamically.  Double-check your build settings.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I managed to solve this.. First, I tried to reference `.a` files (instead of the `dylib` ones) to the project.

But it still didn't seem to work, only when I changed the path from
`libboost_X.a` to the full path `/usr/foo/bar/libboost_X.a` in `Build Phases -> Other Linker Flags` it seemed to solve the problem.